# Prove this formula relating number of primes and semi-primes?

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, semiprimes

I think I have a messy proof which enables me to state for all $m > 2$ **being a prime number**:

$$ \sum_{k=2}^{m-1} \pi(2k)  - m+2 = \pi(m)+2S(m^2)  $$

Where $\pi(x)$ is a function which counts the number of primes $\leq x$ and $S(x)$ is the **number of odd square free semi primes less** $\leq x$. Can you prove the same? (I'll be putting my own proof later). Using prime number theorem I can get bounds for $S(m^2)$ are there better bounds available?

**For example**

Let $m=3$:

$$\implies  \pi(4) -3+2 = 1 = 1 = \pi(3) + 2 S(9)  $$

Let $m=5$:

$$\implies  \pi(4) + \pi(6) + \pi(8) - 5+2 = 6 = \pi(5) +2 S(25) $$

Let $m=7$:

$$ \implies \pi(4) + \pi(6) +\pi(8) +\pi(10)+\pi(12) - 7+2= 13 =  \pi(7) + 2S (49)$$

Comment: Show us your proof so we can fathom the thinking behind the formula.

Comment: It's wrong unfortunately. For $m=100$, $\sum_{k=2}^{m-1}\pi (2k)-m+2=2365$, and $S(m^2)= 2600 $.

Comment: @Asif $100$ is not a prime

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Still it's wrong. For $m=97$, $\sum_{k=2}^{m-1}\pi(2k)-m+2=2235$ and $S(m^2)=2458$.

Comment: @Asif I caught the error it should work now :)

Comment: On the left side of your first display, you have a sum on $k$ of a summand with no $k$ in it. Please take the time to get your question right. Repeated edits are a bad look.

Comment: @KeithBackman I'll try to explain (later in an answer) it but essentially I'm using combinatorics ...

Comment: @MoreAnonymous your formula is wrong again. Please check few examples using any programming language. For $m=47$, $\sum_{k=2}^{m-1}\pi (2k)-m+2=589$, and $S(m^2)=435$. You can include your proof too.

Comment: Nine versions in 12 hours. Do you really know what you want to ask, More?

Comment: By PNT, the number of semiprimes with both factors lower than $N$ is $\frac{N^2}{(\ln N)^2}$ roughly .